# Connectionstring VS asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with connection with DB by connectionstring. 
Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf; Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False";
```

And visual Studio is telling that the error is in parameter AttachDbFilename - accurately with this slash after "|Data Directory|". I tried using 2 slashes - no results. I am using VS 2013. The path to database is ok. I don't know where the problem is.
I made a connection by component ant there the connectionstring was exactly like my connection ant this solution was working.

Comment: You need two slashes also after (LocalDB) or add the string verbatim character before the string @"Data Source ...."

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of escaping the connection string, just use `\\` every time you want to use `\`:

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf; Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False"
```